# BLDC Calculation for Back EMF

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, math, electrical, back-emf

I have a brushless DC Motor that i am considering buying from [hobbyking.com](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-trackstar-1-8th-sensored-brushless-motor-2100kv.html) with 2100Kv (RPM/v) i am trying to follow the equation on [Wikipedia's motor constants page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_constants) i have included the equation here but i am having difficulty understanding whether i am using the calculation correctly. [image: Motor Torque Constant]

My calculation is 60/(2 x π x 2100) = 0.00454 Nm/A and this should be the value of Kt described above, also because Kt = Ke my back EMF constant will also be 0.00454?

Can anyone help me understand if this is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.

\$K_t\$ is approximately equal to \$K_e\$ (approximatly as \$K_e\$ is defined as open-terminal voltage and \$K_t\$ is defined at rated current & the machine may be saturating)

\$K_v\$ is the reciprocal of \$K_e\$

The units of \$K_t\$ are \$\frac{Nm}{A}\$

The units of \$K_e\$ are \$\frac{V}{\omega}\$  (NOTE: from a magnetic point of view this is peak line-line voltage...)

so... 2100\$\frac{rpm}{v}\$ == 219.911 \$\frac{rad/s}{V}\$ = \$K_e\$

Thus taking the reciprical of \$K_e\$

\$K_e = \frac{1}{K_v}\$ = 0.0045473

Comment: your answer seems correct but i am unsure as to whether i understand it, where did you get the 219.911 what calculation did you do to get that and could i use the 0.0045473 in other equations such as to find torque at a given current 0.0045473*105=0.0154nm?

Comment: 219.911 is the Kv expressing in rad/s/V    as oppose to rpm/V. Basically 2100*(2pi/60).  This is exactly the same as the wiki equation you have stated EXCEPT each step is very clear rather than a non-derived equation being used without any information as to what is being done.

Comment: also 0.0045473*105 = 4.774665Nm.... ie  105A would produced 4.77Nm of torque. do you really mean 104Amps.

Comment: Yes 105amps I know it sounds a lot but I'm working with RC hobby motors. Off topic I'm programming a calculator application for motors so it's easier for people to plug in values and get an answer.

Comment: Well it isn't a lot, its a relative consideration. The reason I asked did you mean 105A is because your maths does not make sense. You wrote: " 0.0045473*105=0.0154nm? "  while 0.0045473*105 = 4.774665Nm   thus either your current was wrong or your maths was wildly wrong.

Comment: Apologies clearly I must of been sleeping while using the calculator.

Comment: :) sorted now ..